# Slideshow business theme on every page

Tags: javascript

I have the business drupal theme aplied on a test site, in this theme u have a slideshow on the front page. I wanted to display it on every page so I copied following code to page-tl.php

```
    <?php if (theme_get_setting('slideshow_display','business')): ?>
    <?php 
    $url1 = check_plain(theme_get_setting('slide1_url','business'));
    $url2 = check_plain(theme_get_setting('slide2_url','business'));
    $url3 = check_plain(theme_get_setting('slide3_url','business'));
    ?>
      <div id="slider">
        <div class="main_view">
            <div class="window">
                <div class="image_reel">
                    <a href="<?php print url($url1); ?>"><img src="<?php print 

base_path() . drupal_get_path('theme', 'business') . '/images/slide-image-4.jpg'; ?

>"></a>
                    <a href="<?php print url($url2); ?>"><img src="<?php print 

base_path() . drupal_get_path('theme', 'business') . '/images/slide-image-5.jpg'; ?

>"></a>
                    <a href="<?php print url($url3); ?>"><img src="<?php print 

base_path() . drupal_get_path('theme', 'business') . '/images/slide-image-6.jpg'; ?

>"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="descriptions">
                    <div class="desc" style="display: none;"><?php print check_markup

(theme_get_setting('slide1_desc','business')); ?></div>
                    <div class="desc" style="display: none;"><?php print check_markup

(theme_get_setting('slide2_desc','business')); ?></div>
                    <div class="desc" style="display: none;"><?php print check_markup

(theme_get_setting('slide3_desc','business')); ?></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="paging">
                <a rel="1" href="#">1</a>
                <a rel="2" href="#">2</a>
                <a rel="3" href="#">3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- EOF: #banner -->
    <?php endif; ?>



  <?php print $messages; ?>

  <?php if ($page['homequotes']): ?>
  <div id="home-quote"> <?php print render($page['homequotes']); ?></div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($page['home_high1'] || $page['home_high2'] || $page['home_high3']): ?>
    <div id="home-highlights" class="clearfix">
     <?php if ($page['home_high1']): ?>
     <div class="home-highlight-box"><?php print render($page['home_high1']); ?></div>
     <?php endif; ?>
     <?php if ($page['home_high2']): ?>
     <div class="home-highlight-box"><?php print render($page['home_high2']); ?></div>
     <?php endif; ?>
     <?php if ($page['home_high3']): ?>
     <div class="home-highlight-box remove-margin"><?php print render($page

['home_high3']); ?></div>
     <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Now the sliding effect is gone (except on the front page), so I thought that there was missing javascript. However I can't find a solution...

U can see the problem on [Click for problem here](http://karelmaes.stijnaerts.be)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also include the javascript files on every page instead of only on the front page.

If you look at the `template.php` file in the theme folder, at the end of the file:

```
/**
 * Add javascript files for front-page jquery slideshow.
 */
if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'business') . '/js/sliding_effect.js');
}
```

You should remove the if statement to make it load on every page:

```
/**
 * Add javascript files for front-page jquery slideshow.
 */
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'business') . '/js/sliding_effect.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to review your code, your sliding effects javascript file is missing from your other pages except for the front page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://karelmaes.stijnaerts.be/sites/all/themes/business/js/sliding_effect.js?n8jrx6"></script>
```

Above missing.

You can check this out for more information [Adding Javascript to themes](https://drupal.org/node/304255)